# Checkboxes changed state? How to find out which checkboxes have changed their state

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, buttonclick

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Repeater_Checkbox
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            repeater.DataSource = PopulateCollection();
            repeater.DataBind();
        }

        public CollectionProfiles PopulateCollection()
        {
            var lista = new CollectionProfiles();

            var p1 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "asdas", ProfileID = 1, ProfileStatus = 1};
            lista.Add(p1);

            var p2 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "asdasd", ProfileID = 2, ProfileStatus = 0};
            lista.Add(p2);

            var p3 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "nsadsdot", ProfileID = 3, ProfileStatus = 1};
            lista.Add(p3);

            var p4 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "gluposti", ProfileID = 4, ProfileStatus = 1};
            lista.Add(p4);

            var p5 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "asdaile", ProfileID = 5, ProfileStatus = 0};
            lista.Add(p5);

            var p6 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "sdfsdf", ProfileID = 6, ProfileStatus = 1};
            lista.Add(p6);

            var p7 = new Profile {ProfileDesc = "dfsdf", ProfileID = 7, ProfileStatus = 1};
            lista.Add(p7);

            return lista;
        }

        protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var taaLista = PopulateCollection();
            var someItem = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("checkbox");
            var profileID = Convert.ToInt32(someItem.Attributes["data-id"]);

            foreach (var item in taaLista)
            {
                if ((item.ProfileID == profileID) && (item.ProfileStatus == 1))
                {
                    someItem.Checked = true;
                    return;
                }
                someItem.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        public class CollectionProfiles : Collection<Profile>
        {

        }
}
```

So far so good. I'm handling the OnItemDataBound event to check those textboxes that show profiles with the property Profile.StatusID set to 1.

Now i want to capture all changes. Say if a user unchecks a checkbox or checkes a previously unchecked checkbox I'd like to save the ID's of those Profiles in a list. How do I proceed.

Thanks in advance. I'd appreciate even if you give me ideas to revolve around. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the [Checkbox changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) after this you can determine if it is your collection or not and add or remove it accordingly

Comment: Yea I knew such event existed but can I use it without posting back immediately? For instance, can I have an event handler for that event and only fire that event when a user clicks the button?